# SQL запрос на выборку с датой

Tags: sql, база-данных, request

Пробовал писать различными способами но постоянно эта ошибка, нигде не нашел нормального объяснения работы с датой.
[image: Тот же запрос с решеткой]

[image: Таблица в режиме конструктора]

[image: Таблица из которой производится выборка]

[image: Написанный SQL запрос и ошибка]

Comment: Вы сравниваете дату-время (поле) и строку (значения границ диапазона). Литералы даты в MS Access ограничивают символом `#`, а не кавычкой.

Comment: Я делал и с решеткой и с другими символами(вверху добавил фото с #)

Comment: Ну если не можете элементарно прочитать справку по форматам литералов, используйте преобразование строкового литерала в дату с помощью функции `CDate()`.